# Broken layout when adding attribute data-clearing to ul element zurb-foundation framework

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks

When adding data-clearing attribute to my list element the layout brakes.

This is the code:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348.png" class="th">
            <img id="3" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348/thumbnails/96x96/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350.png" class="th">
            <img id="4" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350/thumbnails/96x96/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352.png" class="th">
            <img id="5" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352/thumbnails/96x96/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354.png" class="th">
            <img id="6" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354/thumbnails/96x96/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357.png" class="th">
            <img id="7" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357/thumbnails/96x96/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
        </ul>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Image 1]

If I remove data-clearing attribute the layout is displayed properly:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 clearing-thumbs">
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348.png" class="th">
            <img id="3" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348/thumbnails/96x96/f5f8ad26819a471318d24631fa5055036712a87e20131118152348.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350.png" class="th">
            <img id="4" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350/thumbnails/96x96/30420d1a9afb2bcb60335812569af4435a59ce1720131118152350.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352.png" class="th">
            <img id="5" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352/thumbnails/96x96/d997e1c37edc05ad87d03603e32ad495ee2cfce120131118152352.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354.png" class="th">
            <img id="6" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354/thumbnails/96x96/3b15be84aff20b322a93c0b9aaa62e25ad33b4b420131118152354.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357.png" class="th">
            <img id="7" src="http://zemunskioglasi.sajt/uploads/images/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357/thumbnails/96x96/9c3dcb1f9185a314ea25d51aed3b5881b32f420c20131118152357.png" alt=" sad ssadsad sad sad ">
        </a>
    </li>
        </ul>
```

And the image:

[image: Image 2]

Other scripts besides foundation framework which I have included are jQuery and modernizr, tried removing modernizr to see if it causes a problem but the result is the same.

Comment: Are you using Foundation 5?

Comment: yes the latest foundation. today downloaded.

Comment: Moved to twitter bootstrap, nevertheless would like this fixed for future use.

Answer (score 0):

It seams they didn't prepared the clearing to work with small-grid-block.

If you add the following css should fix the problem:

`.small-block-grid-3[data-clearing] li {
  margin-right: 0;
}`